# Xdebug crashes apache

Tags: php, apache, xampp, xdebug

My Xdebug works fine when I use eclipses' internal browser but when I use it in an external browser apache crashes.

I am using xampp and on windows 7 64 bit. If someone needs more information let me know.

For some reason if I have the variables tab open in the php debugger in eclipse it crashes apache. So to stop it I just can't have variables tab open while debugging. So this avoids the problem but doesn't fix it. I would like to be able to have this tab. Any suggestions?

Comment: Apache rarely crashes without an error log, so look there & see what you can find. Then again: most probably there's a version mismatch, and you'll probably have to reinstall one of the 3 components anyway, so getting the latest of everything is not a bad step.

Comment: Sometimes I've crashed Apache (segfault) when using XDebug and Eclipse, but it only happens when I have some kinds of Watches set and enabled. Try disabling them all and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: The error log only has a few notices but no errors. And what are Watches? would they be in php.ini or something?

Comment: "Watches" are in the Eclipse IDE - variables/expressions that you are "watching" whilst debugging

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the XDebug build and type does not match your apache & php build and type...

Apache compiled with VS.NET 2008 (VC9) for 32bit and using PHP as a module would require XDebug: 32bit, VC9, Thread Safe.

http://xdebug.org/download.php

Also, you could test another WAMP package that comes with XDebug (for example WampDeveloper) and if it also does not work for you, it's probably not a build mismatch issue.

Comment: I used this page http://www.xdebug.org/find-binary.php to determine which xdebug to download and thats when it started working in eclipse. So I'm pretty confident I have the right version. Why would it work in eclipse and not in an external browser?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I got this working

Eclipse 3.6.1 (because on later versions key shortcut for putting line comment don't work)
Xampp 1.7.4
Xdebug 2.1.2

The trick is to change php from VC6 to VC9 and then it just works correctly.
BTW. It's the variables panel that causes xdebug to crash apache on php VC6.

Remember to get VC9 version of xdebug for new php AND if you put your new php in directory other than
\xampp\php, then on phpinfo(); you'll see that there's no php.ini loaded so just rename old php (co you can swich them from one to other anytime) and put new php in the same directory in which original php was in "\xampp\php" and copy your php.ini (because paths doesn't change). Also remember to obtain any additional php extensions you've been using in VC9 version for new php and put them in "\xampp\php\ext"

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm most of what t0meck said. Except I've moved up to xampp-win32-1.7.7-VC9 which has PHP 5.38. Taking the phpinfo() results from that to Xdebug's [custom installation analyzer](http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php), it specifies the php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll, but the problem isn't entirely eliminated. As I've documented in my 'notes to self' page, the following is working for me.

After following the above procedure, the 'run as' should work on the first try, but the 'debug as' may crash Apache at every attempt. This is an issue that has driven many people to severe distraction. There is an apparent bug exposed using the debug perspective. At the top center of the perspective is a window with two tabs, the variable view and the breakpoint view. Usually, Apache crashes only when the variable view is highlighted, so highlight the breakpoint view instead. Then set a breakpoint on your project. Now, if you are one of the chosen, you will be able to step through the script using the debugger, but when you switch to the variable view it may still crash Apache. What a drag. Repeat the process and the next time you should actually see the variables and the problem will magically go away, until you restart the project. Just repeat the procedure and be satisfied with being one of the lucky ones.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't know if this help, I have same kind of issue, but it relate to array depth xdebug >handle in Variables view. And you can change it. Widnow > Preferences > PHP > Debug > >Installed Debug > Xdebug > Configure enlarge the "Max array depth" solved my issue.

http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=658#c1767

Just set it to 10 or bigger and it should work